# Run OpenCV commands on command Prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, python, opencv

I am completely new to doing these things, so please bear with me.

To learn more about using OpenCV, I installed it with pip for python 3.6.5.
This worked fine at first, but eventually, I started digging into training my own haar cascade. This requires that I run some OpenCV commands in a terminal. Although I have added python to PATH and can execute pip and python commands from command prompt, I cannot find a way to access python modules(in this case opencv) from the command prompt.

Would it be possible to run this command:
`opencv_createsamples -img watch5050.jpg -bg bg.txt -info info/info.lst -pngoutput info -maxxangle 0.5 -maxyangle 0.5 -maxzangle 0.5 -num 1950`
from the command prompt without having to build it from source.

All help is appreciated.

OS: Windows 10

Python Version: 3.6.5

OpenCV Version: 3.4.2